# Start ReactJS/Electron App outside desktop enviroment on Raspbian

Tags: reactjs, raspberry-pi3, raspbian

I'm looking at running my ReactJS/Electron App before the desktop environment engages on the rpi 3. I have my project locating in my home folder of the default Pi account and somehow I need to have it run `npm start` (Starts Flask/React App) and `npm run electron` then display my program outside of the general desktop environment. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to achieve this by creating a bash script to start your application and placing it in the project folder:

```
#! /bin/bash
npm start &
npm run electron
```

In order to start the app when the rpi3 you can place it in `/etc/rc.local`:
`/home/pi/path/to/script/start &`. Note the `&` at the end, since the script might block the boot otherwise.

If the X server is not running when the application tries to start electron, it might fail. In order to prevent this, you can run electron with a virtual X server. For this you can install `xvfb` (`sudo apt-get install xvfb`), and instead of `npm run electron` use:

`xvfb-run --server-args="-screen 0 1024x768x24" npm run electron`.

I am not really sure what you mean by displaying the program outside the DE. You might want to provide more information on this one to get an answer.